# Auditing in Express.js Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, audit, audit-logging

Im looking at universal way to audit the express middleware that I have written for some APIs.

I have come up with several ways of doing but none seems that efficient to me. For now I'm only wanting to log to console or a log file but later on I will be looking at a datastore.

- I can quite easily use a "logging" library such as bunyan in the API routing to do this. But this means Il have to call the logging function everywhere that I want to audit.
- Use a central function such as given in the snippet to do the logging. This is nice way to log the request/response of the APIs but doesn't help when it comes to auditing the critical information such as auditing a user id from a user registration. Or auditing an email address when a user logs in.

  ```
  function auditUserAction(apiFunction) {

      function jsonWrapper(funcToWrap, userAction) {
          return function() {
              userAction.jsonResponse = arguments[0];
              return funcToWrap.apply(this, arguments);
          }
      }

      return function() {
          req = arguments[0];
          res = arguments[1];

          // Overriding json method so we can capture the json response
          res.json = jsonWrapper(res.json, userAction);
          userAction.url = req.url;
          userAction.userId =  req.headers.user_id;
          userAction.referer = req.headers.referer;
          userAction.browserAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];
          result = apiFunction.apply(this, arguments);
          userAction.responseStatusCode = res.statusCode;
          userAction.responseBody = res.body;
          logger.info("Action", userAction);
          return result;
      }
  }
  ..........
  router = require('express').Router();
  router.post('/users', auditUserAction(createUser));
  ```

Is there a better strategy than this ? Ive searched the web but couldn't find anyway of doing this elegantly.